# HTML5 Progress Element Animation Jittery

Tags: jquery, html, progress

I started playing with the HTML5 `<progress>` element to use on a project.  I noticed that the element's animation is jittery, but while animating it with jQuery (fading, for example), the bar's animation will be super smooth.  Anyone have any idea why that's happening?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/Vkg8S/1/)

Comment: Do you have an example of the "jittery" animation?

Comment: @KirKill On my screen, the top bar that continually fades in and out has the loading bar moving smoothly, the bottom bar is the one who has an unsmooth animation.

Comment: It must be very browser-dependant, using chrome I couldn't even see the progress blue thingy, I saw on firefox how it was jittery.

Comment: @KirKill I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu and I get an ugly gray bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes back to this, HTML5 progress bars' appearance fluctuates depending on what OS/ browser you use.  If you are like me, on an Ubuntu machine with Chrome, you'll find the default progress animations will have a skitter to them.  Somehow jQuery animation allows it to render smoothly.

Why this is done this way on Ubuntu/ Chrome I don't know.